# How to debug Node.js Azure Functions in WebStorm (on a Mac)

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, webstorm, azure-functions-core-tools

My setup is

- TypeScript 3.5
- Azure Functions Core Tools 2.7.1480
- WebStorm 2019.2
- MacOs 10.14.6

To run the functions locally I have the start script in my `package.json` defined as follows:

```
"start": "npm run build:dev && cd dev/dist && env $(cat ../../.env | grep -v ^# | xargs) func start",
"build:dev": "rimraf dev/dist && webpack --mode development --config ./tools/build/webpack.js && cp-cli src/local.settings.json dev/dist/local.settings.json && cd dev/dist && func extensions install --package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus --version 3.0.0-beta8",
```

This means I build my sources and then basically call `func start` in the build directory.

How can I attach the WebStorm debugger to step through my code?

Comment: please see if the solution in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688100/azure-functions-how-to-debug-in-webstorm works for you

Comment: Unfortunately not. It is the right direction but a lot more (for my case at least) is missing. I managed to extend it so it builds the sources beforehand, installs the extensions and runs with the correct node version in the correct directory. But then it seems that env vars are missing despite having them explicitly defined. I always get the error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: provider" which seems only to appear if the env vars are not set correctly.

Comment: did you try defining them in your run configuration, *Environment:* field?

Comment: Yes I did. Thats the strange thing that they get ignored. I took the command that WebStorm builds and pasted it into the terminal along with the environment variables and that worked. Which means that somehow they are ignored :-/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688100/azure-functions-how-to-debug-in-webstorm, and the diffs are  1.  install dependencies according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688100/azure-functions-how-to-debug-in-webstorm  2. use `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-functions-core-tools/lib/main.js` as JavaScript File.

Answer (score 0):

What I did not realize is that you are **only** able to set env vars via the `local.settings.json` (which btw you should not check in with your repo). You can not use system env variables like with a regular node project.